# sendTextMessage not working for some users on 5.0.2

Tags: android

My app sends a registration sms when users first installs, but I'm noticing the it never shows up on my server for users who have Android 5.0.2 (possibly 5.0.x, not that many users yet)

Nothing showing up in crashalytics for these users, and I installed 5.0.2 on my own phone and worked fine, but it wasn't a stock version which I'm having trouble finding.

Code paste below, any ideas?

Thanks!

```
      try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();         
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);
         } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Please print and see the exception if there is any error and please make sure you've given `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: I've been unable to reproduce at home, so I don't know if there was an exception. I can modify future versions to send it to me next time a 5.0.2 user downloads tho I suppose.

Comment: please type `Log.v("SMS_TEST", ex.toString());` in your catch block. see the `LogCat` by searching `SMS_TEST` for the exception.

Comment: This sounds like something I could only do if I was able to reproduce the problem myself, I have not been able to do that. I'm just looking to see if this is a problem anyone has already seen on 5.0.2

Comment: I'm not aware of any problems with SMS specific to that Android version. Is it happening only on a certain brand of phone, maybe? Do you have that info?

Comment: @GemmaB89 I've worked this code in 5.0.2 handsets. I don't get any error. If you done properly sure it'll work.

Comment: Galaxy Core Prime, Galaxy A3, HTC one... only thing they have in common form the basic data I collect is they are all 5.0.2, hasn't happened on another version yet. I target api 22 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Oop, I was wrong. The service center bug was in 5.0. But if that's the problem, they shouldn't be able to send any SMS. In any case, you'll have to pull more info from a failing device; e.g., the stack trace (if there is one), the result code from the `PendingIntent` you can set as the fourth parameter in `sendTextMessage()`, etc. If you can't resolve the problem, a fallback solution would be to start the user's SMS app via `Intent`, and have them send it manually.

Comment: OK, guess I'll just have to do some updates that can catch both the stack trace and the result code. Thanks for the advice guys!